# how do I get the user's first name on Liferay?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I'm new to both Liferay and Java and I've been struggling for a day on how to get the user firstname, the documentation on this product is really poor so any help would be highly appreciated.
So I'am working on a portlet and i want it to display the users first name, this is the view.jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletPreferences" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.model.UserModel " %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />


<liferay-ui:success key="success" message="Greeting saved
       successfully!" />

<%
PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();
String greeting = (String)prefs.getValue(
"greeting", "Hello! Welcome to our portal.");
%>
<%

%>
<p><%= greeting %></p>
<portlet:renderURL var="editGreetingURL">
<portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/edit.jsp" />
<portlet:param name="userName" value="Test" />

</portlet:renderURL>

<p><a href="<%= editGreetingURL %>">Edit greeting</a></p>
```

I already played with the usermodel class or interface, I actually found the method :getFirstName() but I just cant get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another alternative would be to use the Liferay ThemeDisplay like so:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme" %>
<liferay-theme:defineObjects />

<%= themeDisplay.getUser().getFirstName() %>
```

Although I'd advise against using JSP Scriptlets in your code, and do this in Java in your portlet class code.

~~ EDIT: Adding alternative to use User more than once  ~~

An example of useing a mixture of Tony's and my approaches would be like so:

```
<%= com.liferay.portal.model.User user = themeDisplay.getUser(); %>
```

~~ EDIT 2: To do this in Java code ~~

See my Gist here: https://gist.github.com/4060650

it can be further simplified with using JSTL to get rid of all scriptlets.

Comment: thank you, this seems to be working, i'm trying to use Tony's approach to user the variable later on the program, but Im also upvoting this one, thank you

Comment: Thanks for the vote up! You could use a mixture of both approaches, by using com.liferay.portal.model.User user = themeDisplay.getUser();

Comment: excelente, I'm about to mark this as accepted, just one question, do you know how to do this on a java class instead of jsp?

Comment: I do indeed, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Added a GIST to GitHub with how to do in Java.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19447/discussion-between-jonny-and-rvs)

Comment: +1. One addition: you can avoid using scriptlets and use Expression Language to do the same thing, just use this: `${user.firstName}`. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding to the jsp:

```
<% 
com.liferay.portal.model.User user = 
      com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getUser(request);
String firstName = user.getFirstName();
%>
<p>User First Name=<%= firstName %></p>
```

I added the full package for ease of understanding.

Comment: It's one of the JSP implicit objects (see http://www.gulland.com/courses/jsp/objects). It is of type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest and it is available by default (implicitly) in any JSP page.